# Get a public link after uploading to Google Cloud Storage using JavaScript Client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I used Google Cloud Storage JavaScript Client Library to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage. Then I want to get a public link that I want to share with my friends without needing Google account. I tried to reuse [the JavaScript example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples) with insertObject as the following codes:

```
 var request = gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
          'method': 'POST',
          'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
          'x-goog-acl','public-read',
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
          },
```

Upload successfully in my google cloud storage bucket (myphoto_upload). But I can not access via https://storage.cloud.google.com/myphoto_upload/brv_brown.png. I tried to replace `'x-goog-acl','public-read'`, with `'acl' : [{'entity': 'allUsers', 'role': 'READER'}],`
        OR `'body':{'entity': 'allAuthenticatedUsers', 'role': 'READER'}`, But the result is the same. Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a typo. It should be `:` instead of `,` after `x-goog-acl`.

Second, `x-goog-acl` is a header, so it it should be included in the headers.

Comment: 'headers': {'x-goog-acl':'public-read',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'}
Is it right? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I think your question involves you uploading a file to GCS and then allowing others to download a file. If you're asking about others anonymously uploading files to your bucket, that's a different matter. Let me know if I've misunderstood.

If you are programmatically generating public links to objects, the easiest way is to just use one of these two URL patterns:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/myphoto_upload/brv_brown.png
https://myphoto_upload.storage.googleapis.com/brv_brown.png
```

Or, as code:

```
"https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucket_name + "/" + object_name
```

As long as the ACL contains allUsers:READER, those URLs will work fine anonymously.

Comment: the update like 'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart','predefinedAcl':'publicRead'}, worked well through your URL patterns. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this library : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php#google-cloud-storage-ga

Use as following :

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => '123456789' // use your own project ID
]);

//this can be created with other ENV mode server side
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.dirname(__FILE__) . '/gauth.json');

/*
 * For public access : 
 * https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME].png
 */
$bucket->upload(
   fopen('data3.txt', 'r'), ['predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead']
);
```